# Write bytes from blob IMAGE into a txt file

Tags: java, pdf, blob, document, corrupt

I wrote this code to convert one of my documents from "blob" IMAGE to txt file. Export works properly. When I open the file, it not contains only text but another the information, like file name, path and then obscure information.
I attach an example:
        File name: new 1.txt
        Text original file: CIAO6

ÐÏà¡±á                >  þÿ                                   þÿÿÿ          ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿýÿÿÿþÿÿÿþÿÿÿþÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿR o o t   E n t r y                                               ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ         À      F             €N&¥¥÷Ð           O l e 1 0 N a t i v e                                              ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ                                       `       C o m p O b j                                                    ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ                                        L                                                                            ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ                                                   þÿÿÿ                þÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿ þÿ
   ÿÿÿÿ      À      F   OLE Package        Package ô9²q                                                                \   new 1.txt C:\Users\stefano\Desktop\new 1.txt    7   C:\Users\STEFAN~1.CER\AppData\Local\Temp\new 1 (2).txt    CIAO6   C : \ U s e r s \ S T E F A N ~ 1 . C E R \ A p p D a t a \ L o c a l \ T e m p \ n e w   1   ( 2 ) . t x t       n e w   1 . t x t *   C : \ U s e r s \ s t e f a n o\ D e s k t o p \ n e w   1 . t x t

```
 protected void onEventImpl(Event event)
            {
                 ...
                String fileName = aaDocumentoMultimedia.getPercorso();
                byte[] documento = aaDocumentoMultimedia.getDocumento();
                Date docData = aaDocumentoMultimedia.getDataRegistrazione();
                if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(fileName))
                {
                    migrazioneDocumentiManager.writeFileOnDisk(fileName, documento, docData);
                }
                 ...
            }



@Override
public void writeFileOnDisk(String fileName, byte[] documento, Date registrationData) throws SQLException, FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    ByteArrayInputStream input = null;
    FileOutputStream output = null;
    try
    {
        (new File(getPathFile(registrationData))).mkdirs();

        input = new ByteArrayInputStream(documento);
        output = new FileOutputStream(new File(getPathFile(registrationData) + fileName));

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
        int n = 0;
        while (-1 != (n = input.read(buffer)))
        {
            output.write(buffer, 0, n);
        }
        output.flush();

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (input != null)
        {
            input.close();
        }
        if (output != null)
        {
            output.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the word "convert" makes no sense in your case - you arent converting anything. At all. You simply write bytes into a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, two points:

- You have to ensure this code is executed within the data base session, other way you won't read correctly blob content.
- Although you flushed output stream, you don't close input/output streams, it would be nice.

Considerations away, your code is ok, so, are you sure your blob content is ok? You could test your blob content with some apps as squirrelSql. Maybe your problem is when storing blob?

Instead the while bucle, you could also use `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils` from apache-commons-io (I used 2.4) this is what I used to convert from blob to files:

```
FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(inStream, blobFile);
```

With this approach you won't need outStream, length, size and buffer.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I answer immediately:
* I have the blob file and export works.
* I closed the input/out I but I did not write this code here.
* The blob on db is it's correct.

Comment: I tried it with your new code but still persists Error. I can not even open files with other extensions correctly, as .xls, docx

Comment: I insert other code , maybe the problem is elsewhere

Comment: Not sure, I don't see anything wrong in your code, and I can ensure my code works.  Can you compare size of a file generated with this code and the same file exported from database?

Comment: I did some tests of reading and writing file on disk and worked.
I think that the problem is decoding doing hibernate file blob .
I use Microsoft SQLServer . Field where are the file content is type IMAGE

Comment: I have no experience with mssql, always worked with postgre, oracle, MySQL and hypersonic